# Is there a way to read a loaded webpage locally? (WebView)

Tags: java, android, html, string, webview

Is there something like a method for reading an already loaded page?

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return document.documentElement.outerHTML;})();",new ValueCallback<String>(){
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String str){
        Log.d("HTML", str); 
    }
});
```

`str` is the HTML of the loaded page.

Comment: thank you :) what if I want to call the String str outside of the code?

Comment: @quidproquo you don't want Callback Hell. but it's necessary to communicate with JavaScript.